# How to find the minimum number of intersection points between two polynomials?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, euclidean-geometry

How to find the minimum number of intersection points between two polynomials provided that I have been given pair of points same for both polynomials.

This is my homework question:

"Let $$S={(x_1,y_1),...,(X_{n+2k},Y_{n+2k})}$$

$P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are polynomials with $$P(X_i)=y_i$$ and $$Q(X_j)=y_j$$ for at least $n+k$ points in $S$. What is the minimum number of points in $S$ such that $P(X)$ = $Q(X)$."

I know that degree of each polynomial is $n$ and that the maximum number of intersection points will then be $n$ but I don't have any idea about the minimum number of intersection points. Can anybody guide to how can I find the minimum number of intersecting points?

Comment: Is it that $P$ and $Q$ each touch at least $n+k$ points in $S$ (but the set of $n+k$ points may be different for $P$ and $Q$), or that there is a given set of $n+k$ points that $P$ and $Q$ both touch?

Comment: @angryavian P and Q each touch at least n+k points in S

Answer (score 0):

Let mark power of set $A$ as $N(A)$. Consider two sets: $A=\{(x,y)|(x,y)\in S\land P(x)=y\}$, $B=\{(x,y)|(x,y)\in S\land Q(x)=y\}$. Then $N(A)\geq n+k$, $N(B)\geq n+k$. $N(A\cup B)\leq N(S)=n+2k$.

$N(A\cap B)=N(A)+N(B)-N(A\cup B)\geq n+k+n+k-(n+2k)=n$.

Comment: I think you may have your intersection and union signs swapped there